# HTML5. How to add mouse event in drawn canvas compoent

Tags: javascript, css, html, mouseevent

I want to draw 200 object in canvas.
and add mouse over, mouse click event each of them.

source code like this...
(valiable k is increase)

....
....
    for( k = 0 ; k < 200; k++){
        start = start[k];
            end = end[k];

```
x1 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*start)*0.9;
y1 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*start)*0.9;
x2 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*start)*0.95;
y2 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*start)*0.95;
x3 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*end)*0.95;
y3 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*end)*0.95;
x4 = centerX-radius*Math.sin(-arg*end)*0.9;
y4 = centerY-radius*Math.cos(-arg*end)*0.9; 

Shape(ctx, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,k);

}


function Shape(ctx, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4, num){
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";    
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.lineTo(x3,y3);
    ctx.lineTo(x4,y4);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText(k,(x2+x3)/2,(y2+y3)/2);    
}
```

....
....


my hope is..
if mouse over on shape, display valiable k 
if mouse click on shape, go other url with valiable k parameter

please help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I did something similar, I found it was easier to create a transparent image and place that over my canvas.

Then I used an imagemap with that newly added image.

The result was great and worked perfectly for me.

Anything else that you do will simply be duplicating something the browser already has built in.

Comment: is possible to auto imagemap tag in newly added image?

Comment: Absolutely.  As long you are passing around a set of vertices, which it looks like you are doing, you can easy create an `area` element and add that to your `map`.  You can add `mousein` `mouseout` and `click` handlers to those `area` elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common practice in making games. It's called "picking" or "sprite picking". Here's a great place to start (over on gamedev.stackexchange) that covers a few of your options:

[How can I detect mouse events on sprites in a canvas?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68890/how-can-i-detect-mouse-events-on-sprites-in-a-canvas)

Things to consider:

- How many elements will there be? The more there are, the more performance needs to be considered.
- Are they regularly shaped? If they are, there might be some easy math you can do if they are in a grid or other regular spacing.
- Do you need pixel-perfection? That is, do you really need it to be accurate down to the last pixel? If not, you can try path detection.

Comment: and but I hope build not image